# Python if/elif statement not working correctly

Tags: python, nlp

Please help understand what is wrong with the code below. The code works fine if I pass values up to 34. Once I pass 35 or higher, the output is incorrect.

```
tuk=0
if tuk <= 24:
    print ('The text is very easy to read.')
elif tuk >= 25 & tuk <= 34:
    print('The text is easy to read.')    
elif tuk >= 35 & tuk <= 44:
    print('The text is moderately difficult to read.')
elif tuk >= 45 & tuk <= 54:
    print('The text is difficult to read')
elif tuk >= 55:
    print('The text is very difficult to read')
else:
    print('This is beyond')
```

Comment: `&` is the bitwise operator. You want `and` - the logical operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, but changing the "&" to "and" because "&" is a bitwise logical operator, not a logical one.

For example:

```js
z = 0 := 0b000
a = 1 := 0b001
b = 2 := 0b010
c = 3 := 0b011
d = 4 := 0b100
```

now the result of the expression (a & c) is 0b001 or 1
but in logical expression (a and c) the result will be true, which I suppose you are interested in.